# C. "Перегрузка" функции для массивов разной длины

Tags: c, макросы

Есть структура

```
typedef struct
{
    int serviceRef;
    char buffer[128];
} WriteBlob;
```

Есть функция, которая внутри обрабатывает эту структуру ( `void HandleBlob(WriteBlob* blob)`). Проблема в том, что объект этой структуры передается по сети. И 128 байтов не всегда нужно передавать, т.к. полезной нагрузки может быть 20 байтов, а передается все равно 128. Так вот вопрос, как реализовать работу этой структуры\функции для разных размеров буфера?
Например, я сделаю структуры WriteBlob128, WtireBlob80, WriteBlob64, WriteBlob32, WriteBlob16. Но тогда, мне нужно будет добавлять столько же реализаций функции для каждого из типов.
Можно как-нибудь, с помощью макросов, сделать так, чтобы пользователь определял структуру, например, WriteBlob32, вызывал функцию (макрос) HandleBlob, а компилятор уже сам решит, на основе переданного параметра, какую функцию вызывать...а еще лучше, чтобы пользователь создает объект WriteBlob64, а компилятор делает из этого структуру.

```
typedef struct
{
    int serviceRef;
    char buffer[64];
} WriteBlob;
```

Язык - С 99. Дополнительное требование - размер структуры должен быть известен на момент компиляции.

Comment: Добавьте поле с длиной массива в структуру, записывайте туда кол-во байт, передавайте по сети, определяйте размер данных по данному полю, или же просто определяйте размер данных по длине сообщения. Вам не обязательно передавать то что вам не нужно. Пусть сторона клиента распознает в какую структуру положить данные принятые от сервера.

Comment: Я забыл добавить, что размер структуры должен быть известен на момент компиляции

Comment: а почему есть такое требование?

Comment: Так исторически сложилось. Код древний, я точно не знаю почему так, но старшие коллеги говорят, что нужно знать размер структуры на этапе компиляции. На это какие-то макросы завязаны

Comment: видимо нужно принять волевое решение и разобраться, что к чему и пофиксить это все

Comment: возможно, serviceRef однозначно соответствует размеру структуры. В этом случае задача стает достаточно тривиальной.

Comment: А почему бы не оставить как есть, просто по сети передается определенное количество байт - и исходя из него вызывается соответствующая функция. Просто она не лезет туда, где ничего нет :)

Answer (score 1):

Популярный подход в winapi - первым полем в структуре лежит её размер в байтах.

Comment: Я забыл добавить, что размер структуры должен быть известен на момент компиляции

Comment: Так добавьте к структуре поле размера, но массив оставьте 128 байт, как есть. Просто обрабатывайте не весь массив, а столько ,сколько оказано в поле размера.